# Look for an open file before running code

Tags: excel, vba

I want to look for the needed reference file before running code.

My code will error out with some of the code running if the file is not found.

something like...

```vb
Sub TestByWorkbookName()
    Dim wb As Workbook

    For Each wb In Workbooks
        If wb.Name = "file name" Then
         
            'run code...
    
        End If
        
    Next
    
    MsgBox "File not found"
End Sub
```

I want to run code if the workbook is open and end sub if not open.

Comment: What is the error?  From what you have, if the named file is open, you should be fine... you may want `Like` or `Instr()` to verify that you're getting all parts, but the loop as written should be fine.  Regarding the `msgbox` placement, you may need a check of sorts if a `wb` does not have the name.

Comment: So the name of the workbook is `"file name"` with no extension and no path? Or is just contains the string `"file name"`? Or is `"file name"` just some sort of placeholder for your question?

Comment: @braX.  No, that was just an example.  "file name*.xlsx"

Comment: Your code and the suggested solutons will only check if the workbook is open in the current Excel instance. Is that sufficient?

Comment: @Storax I was just seeing that.  I actually want it to run code if open and end sub  if not open.  I think I'm missing something.

Comment: The code so far will only check if the file is open in the current Excel instance. It could be that the file in question is open in another instance. This means your code will not run although the file is open.

Comment: Something else, what I just saw. You are looping thorugh the workbooks collection, right? That means all the workboos are open in the current instance. What is the check good for then?

Comment: @Storax - thanks for your comments.  I possibly have not explained well.  I don't actually need to loop through workbooks.  I just need to be sure a specific workbook (that the macro uses) is open before starting code string.  I have issues where users do not name the workbook correctly and then the macro runs half way before it realizes the needed workbook is not open.

Answer (score 0):

Quick example for checking if any `wb` has been found:

```
for each wb in workbooks
    if instr(wb.name, "file name")>0 then
        check = 1
        `do stuff
        exit sub
    else
        check = 0
    end if
next wb
if check = 0 then msgbox "File not found."
```

Comment: Thank you Cril, this works but what if I use a wildcard for the name file such as: 
If wb.Name Like "filename*.xlsx" Then

Comment: @RTD With `[Like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator)` you don't need wildcards, as that's inherent.  Using `instr()`, it's finding your phrase in the string being assess, `wb.name` and finds the location of that string and reports a character number; that's why the output is `>0`.  No asterisk needed for either.

Comment: Thank you again.  Different users will have different file names, they will all have the same beginning such as.  "file name A", "file name B" Is there a similar way to go about this if I want to use the same macro with similar file names?

Comment: @RTD well, you have a uniform "file name" in both of those, and as such could use that as your search string.  E.g., I use a similar code for checking if a filename appears whereas updates are made and a new date is appended after the standard file name... I don't have to change my code.  `InStr(UCase(wb.Name), UCase(uniqueString))` gets me from A to B for work.

Answer (score 0):

If I got the OP right he would like to check if a certain workbook is already open in Excel. And in case it is open some code can run then.

My suggestion would be to do it like that

```
Sub RunCode()

    Dim wkbName As String
    wkbName = "myWorkbook.xlsx"     ' only the workbook name is needed, not the full path

    If isWorkbookOpen(wkbName) Then   ' code for this function is below
        ' Run the code you want to run in case the workbook with the name wkbName is open
        Debug.Print wkbName & " is open"
    
    Else
        ' Do not do anything in case the workbook with the name wkbName is not open
        Debug.Print wkbName & " is not open"
    End If

End Sub
```

The following code will be needed for the code above

```
Option Explicit
        
    
Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
    (ByVal hWnd1 As LongPtr, ByVal hWnd2 As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function IIDFromString Lib "ole32" _
    (ByVal lpsz As Long, ByRef lpiid As GUID) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function AccessibleObjectFromWindow Lib "oleacc" _
    (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal dwId As Long, ByRef riid As GUID, _
    ByRef ppvObject As Object) As LongPtr
         
             
    Private Type GUID
        Data1 As Long
        Data2 As Integer
        Data3 As Integer
        Data4(7) As Byte
    End Type
    
    Private Const S_OK As Long = &H0
    Private Const IID_IDispatch As String = "{00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
    Private Const OBJID_NATIVEOM As Long = &HFFFFFFF0
    
    Function getXLApp(hWinXL As LongPtr, xlApp As Excel.Application) As Boolean
        Dim hWinDesk As LongPtr, hWin7 As LongPtr
        Dim obj As Object
        Dim iid As GUID
        
        Call IIDFromString(StrPtr(IID_IDispatch), iid)
        hWinDesk = FindWindowEx(hWinXL, 0&, "XLDESK", vbNullString)
        hWin7 = FindWindowEx(hWinDesk, 0&, "EXCEL7", vbNullString)
        
        If AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hWin7, OBJID_NATIVEOM, iid, obj) = S_OK Then
            Set xlApp = obj.Application
            getXLApp = True
        End If
    
    End Function
    
    Function isWorkbookOpen(wkbName As String) As Boolean
        
        Dim hWinXL As LongPtr
        hWinXL = FindWindowEx(0&, 0&, "XLMAIN", vbNullString)
        
        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
        Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
        
        Do While hWinXL > 0
                    
            If getXLApp(hWinXL, xlApp) Then
                For Each wb In xlApp.Workbooks
                    If wb.Name = wkbName Then
                        isWorkbookOpen = True
                    End If
                Next
            End If
            hWinXL = FindWindowEx(0, hWinXL, "XLMAIN", vbNullString)
        Loop
        
    End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for this Storax.  I'm getting a message that this code needs to be updated to work with 64 bit.
This section is in red.

Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
    (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
    ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long
Private Declare Function IIDFromString Lib "ole32" _
    (ByVal lpsz As Long, ByRef lpiid As GUID) As Long
Private Declare Function AccessibleObjectFromWindow Lib "oleacc" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal dwId As Long, ByRef riid As GUID, _
    ByRef ppvObject As Object) As Long

Comment: @RTD I adjusted the declarations to work with 64-bit

Comment: This is very interesting!  I have all of this in a new module.  I'm getting a type mismatch on "FindWindowEx" when I step through RunCode ().

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change the data type in the subs from `Long`  to `LongPtr` for the handles. Done now.

Comment: One more :)  ByRef argument type mismatch:

Function isWorkbookOpen(wkbName As String) As Boolean

in:  If getXLApp(hWinXL, xlApp) Then

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what your code looks like in your workbook. I tested the code in 32-bit Excel and it is working. If you get stuck with porting it to 64-bit it might be better to open a new question and describe what you did and where you got stuck.

Comment: Thank you Storax for everything!